# How do I extract url from a log file like this? script bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

How do I extract the url from a log file like this using a bash script on Linux?

```
3.249.76.98 - - [12/Aug/2016:06:26:33 +0200] "GET /kod-exempel/dynamic_php_menu/ HTTP/1.1" 301 3859 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output you expect from this example. Do you want _all_ URLs? How do you define a URL? Is `foo.bar` a URL? Or only `http://foo.bar`? Will the URL you are looking for always be the last element before the closing `)`? Will it always have a `+` before it? Does your file have just one line or many?

Comment: I closed this as the question fails to say what the result would be given the sample data.  There is only one URL in that data, and it's the Google user agent URL at the end. It's further unclear if this single line is the complete data or whether there are more lines of input and what they may look like (and whether POST, DELETE, PUT lines are interesting, or whether the data needs to be filtered in any way in particular).

Answer (score 1):

The simplified method is to use:

```
awk '{print $7}' input_file
```

this will produce `/kod-exempel/dynamic_php_menu/`. If you want to add domain and protocol you can add them in `awk` `print` command (just example):

```
awk '{print "https://domain.ext" $7}' input_file
```

Comment: The only URL in the line in the question is `http://www.google.com/bot.html`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, this is the user agent, and IMHO this is not the URL OP want :)